# How to get the id of dynamic input field using change function of select field inside a row in a table?

Tags: javascript, laravel

The problem is, I cant select the right input id of dynamic field inside a row.

```
<script>
$('tbody').on('change', 'select',function(e) //Same row #itemDescription.
{
e.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
type:'get',
url:'{{ route("<add.findItem>") }}' ,
data:{id:id},
dataType:'json',//return data will be json
success:function(data)
{

//THIS IS THE PROBLEM, EVERY TIME THE SELECT CHANGES, IT WILL DISPLAY THE VALUE TO THE LAST CREATED INPUT FIELD NOT CURRENT INPUT FIELD INSIDE A ROW. 
FIELD.
$('#itemDescription_'+ count +'').val(data.itemDescription);
},
error:function()
{
alert("Error Occurred");
}
}
);
});
</script>
```

I expect to display the values to the correct index inside the row.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). We can't help you access the elements in your DOM structure if you don't show us your DOM structure. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of the select inside your table row

```
$(document).on('change', 'tbody tr select', function(){ 
   var dynamicInputVal = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[id^='itemDescription_']").val(); //This line must exactly be here, not in any other function

  $.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url:'{{ route("add.findItem") }}' ,
    data:{id:dynamicInputVal},
    dataType:'json',//return data will be json
    success:function(data){
       alert(dynamicInputVal)
    },
    error:function(){
       alert("Error Occurred");
    }
  });//end ajax



})
```

Your question is not clear, where is the dynamic `input`

Comment: Thank you for the response sir!, the dynamic input field is inside the row with the dynamic select field so I want to return the values to only the current row, but for this code it will return to the last created row.

Comment: I have edited the answer, please check and see if it works. You need to use `$(document)` to find dynamically created content

Comment: It doesn't return a value to the input field sir.

Comment: How is your `HTML` looking like, We are just guessing now. Can you please share the html snippet

Comment: It says undefined sir.

Comment: dont put ` var dynamicInputVal = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[id^='itemDescription_']").val();` inside the success function, it wont work

Comment: Please Try again Sir

Comment: I was able to get the value of that input field sir but how to use it on ajax callback sir? dynamicInputVal.val(data.itemDescription) doesn't work sir.

Comment: What do you want to do in the callback?

Comment: I want to return the value to the dynamicInputVal sir.

Comment: This is your value dynamicInputVal

Comment: I want to return the value to the dynamicInputVal sir. supposedly this is my ajax callback sir $('#itemDescription_').val(data.itemDescription); and your idea sir selected the right id so How to return ajax callback to this dynamicInputVal variable sir?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help sir, I solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your DOM structure it's very hard to help you with this, but fundamentally `this` in your `change` callback will refer to the `select` the change occurred on. You can use jQuery's various [traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to find elements near that specific `select`.

For instance, this would find the first `input` on the same row as the `select` by finding the [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) enclosing `tr` element and then using [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to look within it for the [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) input:

```
$('tbody').on('change', 'select',function(e) {
    var input = $(this).closest("tr").find("input:first");
    // ...
});
```

Then in your ajax callback you'd use `input.val(data.itemDescription);`.

Comment: Thank you for the response sir!, then how to get input field using the dynamic id? "#itemDescription_'+ count +'" is the id of dynamic input field.

Comment: @JeffreyGepiga - Why would you need to? Again, if you show us the structure, we can do a better job of helping you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am with you on that one, we are just doing a guess help now. It would be quick if we were seeing his structure

Comment: Thank you for the idea sir, I solved the problem. Appreciated